# Use distinct in php MongoDB query

Tags: php, mongodb

In my `cars_positions` database and `positions` collection I have this kind of data :

`db.positions.find()`

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536a5cd9e9df25cd8609d286"), "car" : { "type" : "sport", "ref" : "nameOfTheCar1" }, "position" : { "dateTime" : "2014-05-06T06:42:10", "latitude" : "0000.1111", "hemesphere" : "S", "longitude" : "05563.1254"}}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536a5cd9e9df25cd8609d287"), "car" : { "type" : "sport", "ref" : "nameOfTheCar2" }, "position" : { "dateTime" : "2014-05-06T06:43:11", "latitude" : "0000.1111", "hemesphere" : "S", "longitude" : "05563.1254"}}
```

I'm trying to use a distinct into my mongodb query. Here is my current query where I need to iterate all the data to create a proper array with only the last position:

```
    $pipeline = 
        [
            [
                '$match' => 
                    [
                      'car.ref' => ['$in' => $cars],
                      'position.dateTime'  => 
                            [
                                '$gte' => $period['start'],
                                '$lte' => $period['end'],
                            ],
                    ],
            ],
            [
                '$sort' => 
                    [
                      'position.dateTime' => 1,
                    ],
            ],
            [
                '$group' => 
                    [
                      '_id' => ['car.ref'],
                      'lastposition' => ['$last' => '$position'],
                    ],
            ],
        ];

        $command = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command($pipeline);
        $cursor = $mongo->executeCommand('mybase.positions', $command);
```

Original post with the original query : http://pastebin.com/BEC7nUa7

What I would like to achieve is to have a distinct on the car.ref and only get the latest location of any car in the `$cars` array with the date range.

So I could have a final array like this :

```
array (size=1)
  car1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'car.ref' => string 'car1' (length=7)
      'dateTime' => string '2017-01-18T00:00:09' (length=19)
      'latitude' => string '0000.1111' (length=9)
      'hemesphere' => string 'S' (length=1)
      'longitude' => string '05563.1254' (length=10)
   car2 =>
   car3 =>
```

Any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need aggregation. Try something like below.

```
<?php

    $mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

    $cars = ['nameOfTheCar1', 'nameOfTheCar2'];

    $start = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('2012-05-06T06:42:10') * 1000);
    $end = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('2014-05-06T06:42:10') * 1000);   

    $pipeline = 
        [
            [
                '$match' => 
                    [
                      'car.ref' => ['$in' => $cars],
                      'position.dateTime'  => 
                            [
                                '$gte' => $start,
                                '$lte' => $end,
                            ],
                    ],
            ],
            [
                '$sort' => 
                    [
                      'position.dateTime' => 1,
                    ],
            ],
            [
                '$group' => 
                    [
                      '_id' => '$car.ref',
                      'lastposition' => ['$last' => '$position'],
                    ],
            ],
        ];

    $command = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command([
        'aggregate' => 'positions', 
        'pipeline' => $pipeline
        ]);

    $cursor = $mongo->executeCommand('mybase', $command);

    foreach($cursor as $key => $document) {
        var_dump($document);

    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I can't use aggregate with mongoDB driver : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager::aggregate() And what is $position in the group section ?

Comment: Take a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executecommand.php

Comment: There is not a lot of example with MongoDB\Driver and I'm only able to get data with the query from my post. There is no way to enhance this query ?

Comment: no you can't get latest in regular query for each id. You have to use the aggregation. There is an example at th bottom of page.

Comment: Here is another example depending on your version. http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php. `$position`  is the position field from your collection

Comment: On http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.core.php they say that's `This extension is deprecated. Instead, the MongoDB extension should be used.` So that's why I'm using MongoDB\Driver

Comment: alright updated answer to include the setup information. Please replace the placeholder with your values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but when I try to run it I've got this error in mongod : `I QUERY    [conn6] assertion 17287 Can't canonicalize query: BadValue: unknown operator: $match ns:tracks_positions.positions.$cmd query:{ 0: { $match: { car.ref: { $in: [ "car1" ] }, position.dateTime: { $gte: "2016-09-27", $lte: "2016-09-27" } } }, 1: { $sort: { position.dateTime: 1 } }, 2: { $group: { _id: [ "car.ref" ], lastposition: { $last: "$position" } } } }`

Comment: Not entirely sure what the error is about, but updated answer to simplify the nesting of values.

Comment: The post is updated with the pipeline. $mongo contain this : `new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(CONNECTION_URI);`

Comment: Did you try to run the pipeline with the latest update ?

Comment: Yes and the error : `Can't canonicalize query: BadValue: unknown top level operator: $match ns:tracks_positions.positions.$cmd query:{same things here}`

Comment: Sorry for being so long but I couldn't work on it before. I've updated my code with your change but now there is no error in mongod and the var dump display this : http://pastebin.com/2PfN76Ja

Comment: Np. Are your `dates` type of `String` in database ?

Comment: $period['start']  is a `string` like this type : `2016-08-10`

Comment: Okay. I assume that's how it is in the database too. Change it to `date` type so that you can run comparison queries. I can update the answer to change the period as `date` type.

Comment: Updated.Please verify.

Comment: Thanks a lot but same result as my previous pastebin. But I've noticed no log into my console with mongod. Like nothing happen

Comment: Can you go to `mongod` and paste me a sample doc from your collection that you are expecting query to return ?

Comment: This is not wat I posted in my first post ?

Comment: I meant how does your collection look like after you changed the documents to date type.

Comment: The problem is that I can't change data type in mongodb for the moment. And this may not be the problem because even without query on the date I've got the same result as in the previous pastebin. Even if I'm only looking for a `$match` on the `car.ref`

Comment: I ran the same code. I got this as output. http://pastebin.com/P5JhecC1. Can you verify your database name and collection name ?

Comment: Oh... I'm sorry I was using a wrong database name ... Your current code from this post is working. Thanks a lot and sorry for wasting your time on that mistake haha ! This method should be better (in performance) than iterating every position like before.